# Pyinstaller could not generate the execuatable file in WSL system

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am now learning to use Pyinstaller to create stand alone executable from a Python script.

Here is the simple example which I edited in the VS Code remote environment for WSL.

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

def hello ():  
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= 'Hello World!', fg='green', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 200, window=label1)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click',command=hello, bg='brown',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

By using `pyinstaller -F test.py`, I could get the compiled Python file in the folder of "_pyache", in which it could be opened as shown as follows:

[image]

However, when I want to use `pyinstaller --onefile test.py`, we could see there is a new file generated in the folder of `dist`. It has not shown the format of "exe' as other videos/tutorials show. But I could no open it by double-click.

[image]

Is this related with the WSL system that Pyinstaller could not generate the cross-plaform exe? Is my assumption right? Then how can I convert `.py` to `.exe`?

Comment: WSL is Linux, so the generated executable under it will not be a Windows `exe`.  You need to run Windows version of PyInstaller in order to generate a Windows executable.

Comment: have you tried `auto-py-to-exe` ?

Comment: @Jawad, I have not tried this one, I will search that.

Comment: @jawad, I have tried this tool you recommended. It works!